# using powershell to change registry binary data

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell, binary

I understand that with powershell it's possible to change registry values.

for example, here: http://poshcode.org/3504

we can set the properties like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice' -name ProgId IE.FTP
```

**however, is it possible to set these binary values using powershell??**

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Read the value (a byte array)
2. Modify the array element
3. Write the byte array back to the registry key.

Here's an example:

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'

$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
$data[8] = 9
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data
```

Comment: this looks amazing!! when you are doing this $data[8] = 9. does this convert 9 to hex?

Comment: the byte array is an array of decimal values 0-255. see [`system.byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(v=VS.71).aspx). The data is only displayed in base 16 (hex) with the registry editor.

Comment: absolutely amazing answer! how did u know how to do this?